# How can I print $1 and all matching words on line but no other words?

Tags: bash, text-processing

The input looks like this:

```
user1 : MPT_group1
user2 : MPT_group1 MPT_group3  MPT_group4 groupx groupy
user3 : MPT_group2 MPT_group3 groupn
```

I want to get back:

```
user1 : MPT_group1
user2 : MPT_group1 MPT_group3 MPT_group4
user3 : MPT_group2 MPT_group3
```

Thanks.

Comment: What defines "matching" here?

Comment: any word with MPT_* in it.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s : ", $1; for( i=3; i<=NF; i++ ) { if( $i ~ /^MPT_group/ ) { printf "%s ", $i }  } print "" }' input
user1 : MPT_group1
user2 : MPT_group1 MPT_group3 MPT_group4
user3 : MPT_group2 MPT_group3
```

To make that more readable, here is the bare `awk` script portion:

```
{
   printf "%s : ", $1; 
   for( i=3; i<=NF; i++ ) { 
      if( $i ~ /^MPT_group/ ) { 
         printf "%s ", $i }
      } 
   print ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ r=$1 OFS $2; for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^MPT_group/) r=r OFS $i; print r }' file
```

The output:

```
user1 : MPT_group1
user2 : MPT_group1 MPT_group3 MPT_group4
user3 : MPT_group2 MPT_group3
```

Answer (score 0):

With **`grep`**:

```
$ grep -Po '^\S*\s*: (MPT_group\d+\s*)+' infile
user1 : MPT_group1
user2 : MPT_group1 MPT_group3  MPT_group4
user3 : MPT_group2 MPT_group3
```